# Windows phone store app can't be found

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-store

I just developed my first app for windows phone and put it into the windows phone app store. Everything worked fine, I got the message the app was accepted, so I started looking for it in the app store. Many searches later I still couldn't find it.

The other strange part was, that I can't even find it with the direct link which I get under "Link zum Store" (German, stands for: link to store) When I click the link, I 404 page.

Any reason why this is the case, I made the app available in all countries, regions and windows phones 8.1 . The link to the app is: http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=f383f584-a864-4f07-a4bc-5c709f750865

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on when the app got published, it might take some time for it to propagate and become available through direct links or search.

For example, I can already see your app through direct link, I can also see it in Windows Phone Store through that link and install it.

Comment: well this is the funny thing.. I can't see the app throw the direct link, I get a 404 for my own app :D. But I guess I still wait a few days then

Answer (score 1):

it takes a couple of days... MS makes it seem like it will be instantaneous...

My first app took 3 days to "show up"... hurry up and wait :-)

Comment: It seems that new apps take much longer time to propagate to all servers than app updates.